# Fix for flickering when using React forms multiple true onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, jsx

I'm implementing a `multiselect` from [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) where the attribute `multiple={true}` is set. When de box is rendered and I click on an option I wanted to select the entire box is rerendered that causes flickering.

Does someone know how to fix this issue? I looked to several resources but couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Please add the code you are using. My guess would be that you are doing something that causes/forces the box to re-render constantly. Are you doing something getDerivedStateFromProps?

Comment: Which part of the code do you need? I don't use getDerivedStateFromProps. I started using hooks. So I do useState to update the selected items.